# Wait for Ajax function to complete before starting new one

Tags: jquery, ajax, foreach

I have the following script -

```
function getdata(stringArray, Net) {
            if (stringArray, [0] != "") {
                var processing = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < (stringArray, i++) {
                    var username = (stringArray, [i];
                    if (processing === false) {
                        processing = true;
                        $.when(
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "post",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                url: "Default.aspx/getdata",
                                data: JSON.stringify({ test: 'test' }),
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    var json = data.d;
                                    FinalJson = json;
                                    doStuff(Net);
                                },
                                error: function (err) {
                                    alert("Error please retry.");
                                }
                            })
                        ).done(function () {
                            processing = false;
                        });
                    }
                }

            } else {

            }
        };
```

Within `stringArray` there will be a varying number of strings. For each string I want to do an Ajax call, however wait until the call has completed before starting a new one.

I thought that by adding the `processing` variable and initially setting it to false when entering the function, then true right before the ajax call, that on the `.done` setting processing to false would have achieved this.

For some reason it is firing the first Ajax call, and then stopping, instead of on completion of the first call starting the next in the list.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0dvsqkns/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, updated

Added: 
Remove empty strings from `stringArray` utilizing `$.map()` ; check for empty strings at `$.each()` , before further processing

Try (this pattern)

```
$(function () {
    // e.g. , with `html` : `<textarea></textarea>`
    var stringArray = ["","a", "b", "c","", "1", "2", "", "3"];
    var request = function (_string) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/json/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify({
                    "d": _string
                })
            }
        });
    };
    var Net = [];
    var doStuff = function (n) {
        // do stuff 
        // when all requests complete
        $.each(n, function (k, v) {
            $("textarea").append(v + "\n");
        });
    };
    // remove `""` from `stringArray`
    stringArray = $.map(stringArray, function(val, idx) {
      return val != "" ? [val] : null
    });
    $.each(stringArray, function (k, v) {
      // `""` removed from`stringArray` above ,
      // check again
      if (v != "") {
        $.when(request(v))
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
              if (textStatus === "success" 
                 && window.confirm("at index " 
                    + k + " of " + stringArray.length 
                    + " asynchronous requests supplied by `stringArray`,"
                    + "continue")) {
                // do stuff 
                // when each request completes
                var json = data.d;
                // FinalJson = json;
                Net.push(data.d);
                if (Net.length === stringArray.length) {
                    // do stuff 
                    // when all requests complete
                    alert(textStatus + " " + Net.length 
                    + " requests completed");
                    doStuff(Net);
                };
            };
        })
        .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
            $("textarea")
                .val(jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders() 
                 + "\n" + jqxhr.status + "\n" + textStatus 
                 + "\n" + errorThrown + "\n" + jqxhr.responseText)
        });
      };
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/L3jbvnex/

Answer (score 2):

If you really need your ajax requests to process synchronously (one at a time), you can set the option

`async: false`

So your request would look like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "Default.aspx/getdata",
  async: false,
  data: JSON.stringify({ test: 'test' }),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    var json = data.d;
    FinalJson = json;
    doStuff(Net);
  },
  error: function (err) {
    alert("Error please retry.");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .[then](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/#example-1)() function after your $.when(). You cann use it with multiple ajax-calls too.

```
$.when(
    $.ajax(....),
    $.ajax(....)
).then(someFunction);
```